# Unable to install jetpack on my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, curl, jetpack

When trying to install jetpack on my wordpress website, I receive this message: The Jetpack server was unable to communicate with your site http://xx[IXR -32300: transport error: http_request_failed cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds]

What can I do to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time it's because of low resources on cheap shared hostings. Either navigate to your server C-panel / PHP options (on GoDaddy they are inside of "Select PHP version") and increase the following:

- memory_limit
- upload_max_size
- post_max_size
- upload_max_filesize
- max_execution_time max_input_time

If this doesn't work or you don't have access to PHP options then contact your hosting provider and ask them to do it.